# Excel error #value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPyQF.jpg

There is something wrong with my code in MS Excel. If I put "X" in any cell from A1:C10 the value of the D1 will be 1 if not the value will be blank. but there's an error (#VALUE!). Please help me.

Comment: I think this belongs to SuperUser or some other StackExchange site, instead of SO...Not sure tho.

Comment: You need to provide more information: At a minimum what is the code you have in A1:C10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is pretty literal and what you are asking it to do, does Range A1:c10 = "X", is not valid.
You want to replace

```
A1:C10="X"
```

with

```
COUNTIF(a1:c10,"X")>0
```

i.e.:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C10,"X")>0,"1","")
```

One of the many valid ways to accomplish what you are looking to do is to COUNTIF([range],[condition]) and then check if that returns >0.